# iOS: Segmented touchmap over image

Tags: ios, objective-c, image, ios7

I've been trying to find a way to solve this problem, and haven't been able to find anything useful, so forgive me if this is a duplicate of something I couldn't find.

I have, essentially, a large complicated image in the style of a stained glass window in a scroll view so that I can pan and zoom around it. Each of the individual segments of the window has some information associated with it. What I need to be able to do is tap on any of the segments and determine which segment was tapped so that I can display the information. What I'm not sure of is how to do the mapping between touch points and segments. Most of the segments aren't even regular polygon shapes let alone orthogonal squares, so I can't think of a straightforward way to determine which segment I've tapped.

If anybody has any ideas as to how I might go about implementing this, it would be most appreciated!

Cheers

Comment: You can create a plist which store all the information about each and every point on image and when you are going to tap on that point you can show the information which you have stored on plist regarding those points.

Answer (score 0):

Put each individual segment in a different layer. Now you can do hit-testing on what layer was tapped. Your test must be designed so that if a layer was tapped but on a transparent area (i.e. outside its segment), your test will fall through to the next layer behind it. Thus the test will succeed if and when you discover a layer's non-transparent region under the tap. Since it is one segment per layer, the segment is the one corresponding to that layer.

Comment: And see my discussion of "Hit-testing for drawings" in this section: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch18.html#_hit_testing

Comment: Also watch the WWDC 2014 video on scroll views and touchability, which is all about this sort of thing.